# How to completely discharge a mobile device?

Tags: battery, charging

In case of laptops we should remove battery, then turn it off and hold power button for 15 seconds to completely discharge the motherboard. Whats the procedure in case of a smartphone or a tablet with non removable battery?

Comment: Completely discharging a battery can damage it, so you should only discharge a battery if there is no other way. Instead just power off the device, this usually cuts off power of most of the chips in a phone.

Comment: @Robert looks like the question is about discharging the device, not the battery.

Comment: ... which sometimes I have to ask, is there a reason why you want to discharge the device?

Comment: @Andrew T. becase I wanted to clean comtacts with alcohol which isnt dielectric.

Comment: @Robert so I can clean usb ports with non dielectric cleaner safely then?

Comment: @YaY Sorry bit I don't know, I am not familiar with dielectric cleaners.